# update a FSharpMap in a while loop

Tags: dictionary, f#, local, mutable

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let linshi1 = [|1,2|]
    let linshi2 = Array.append linshi1 [|2,3|]
    let map1 = Map.ofArray linshi2
    let mutable it = 1
    while it = 1 do 
        it <- it - 1
        let map2 = map1.Add(3,4)
        let map1 = map2
        printfn "!\n"
    printfn "done"
    0
```

this is my test code. I am trying to update the "map1" in the while loop but the result shows that I failed. So how can I achieve this function? I really need updating a map during reading a Excel file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot "update" [F# map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353880.aspx) as it is immutable data structure, i.e. adding to a map produces another map. It is not clear how you are going to align reading your Excel with updating a map, but you can always do something like

```
let mutable myMap = ...
......
myMap <- (x,y) ||> Map.add <| myMap
```

which creates a new map instance off the old one and then points the original reference to new contents discarding the previous one.

Secondly, when you use `while` expression it creates a new scope so your `let map1=...` shadows "original" `map1` outside the `while`. This "internal" `map1` in turn gets discarded when control is getting back outside of `while`. That's why your manipulations inside `while` do not anyhow affect your "original" `map1`. See [FSharp Programming/Basic Concepts](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Basic_Concepts#Immutable_Values_vs_Variables) for details of scoping and shadowing.

Summing up, you do not need any `while` loop; just convert your snippet to something like the snippet below, where instead of making `map1` mutable it is simply redefined. This is allowed inside functions, and `main` is a function, indeed:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let linshi1 = [|1,2|]
    let linshi2 = Array.append linshi1 [|2,3|]
    let map1 = Map.ofArray linshi2
    let map1 = (3,4) ||> Map.add <| map1
    printfn "%A" map1
    0
```

which being executed will output `map [(1, 2); (2, 3); (3, 4)]` as expected.

Comment: +1 This answer is absolutely right. Just a minor point - you do not really need to change `map1.Add` to something like `(3,4) ||> Map.add <| map1` - I It is perfectly fine to mutate the map by saying `map1 <- map1.Add(3,4)` (and I would definitely prefer this to using fancy operators to confuse the enemy :-))

Comment: @TomasPetricek: Thank you for the reminder that sometimes use of type instance methods may be preferred to type module functions.